# How to change white color to red color in the picture?

Tags: python, opencv

I want to use opencv to change the white color to red color but keep the black parts. How to do it?

[image]

Comment: Segment the white color using `cv2.inRange()`, and replace with new color using the mask as `img[mask == 255] = np.array([0, 0, 255])`

Answer (score 6):

You can numpy to do this.

```
image = np.zeros((400,400,3), dtype="uint8")
image[np.where((image==[0,0,0]).all(axis=2))] = [0,0,255]
```

This will change all pixels in image that have a value of [0,0,0] to [0,0,255] (red)

Answer (score 6):

[The answer by GPPK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47939457/6045800) is wrong for 2 reasons:

1. line #1 is creating a new image, but in the question was asked how to change the color for an existing image.
2. line #2 is changing black colors, not white.

```
image = cv2.imread("Your image path here")
image[np.where((image==[255, 255, 255]).all(axis=2))] = [0, 0, 255]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way of getting good results would be `image[np.where((image>[0,0,0]).all(axis=2))] = [0,0,255]`. Here, you change the non-black pixels to red.